# Validate a form multiple times

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

Is it normal that my validateForm method in Form API doesn't trigger second time i call it?

And if yes, how do i trigger it multiple times? I've got multistep form and i want to validate each step individually. Would be perfect to validate steps with validateForm.

First step can be validated, but on click Next in the second step inputs are not validated anymore, it skips validateForm() method.

**Buttons:**

```
$button = [
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => $this->t('Next'),
      '#attributes' => ['class' => ['btn-primary pull-right button-next']],
      '#name' => 'next_' . $callbackName,
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::ajaxCallbackValidate' . $callbackName,
        'url' => Url::fromRoute('route.name'),
        'options' => [
          'query' => [
            FormBuilderInterface::AJAX_FORM_REQUEST => TRUE,
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ];
```

**validateForm() :**

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);
    $values = $form_state->getValues();

    if ($values['validate_step'] && !empty($values['validate_step'])) {
      switch ($values['validate_step']) {
        case "personal":
          //Validate personal;
          //break;
        // Etc.
```

Edit :
ajaxCallback methods look like that :

```
public function ajaxCallbackValidatepersonal(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
   $ajaxResponse = new AjaxResponse();

    if (count($form_state->getErrors()) == 0) {
      $form['validate_step']['#value'] = "step_2";
    }
    $errors = StatusMessages::renderMessages();
    $ajaxResponse->addCommand(new PrependCommand(
        '#class-name',
        render($errors)
      )
    );

    // Here i was trying to do something with validation, doesn't work
    $form_state->setValidationComplete(FALSE);
    $form_state->setValidationEnforced(TRUE);
    $form['status']['#validated'] = FALSE;
    $form['status']['#sorted'] = False;
    
    $ajaxResponse->addCommand(
      new HtmlCommand(
        '#form_wrapper', $form
      )
    );

    $ajaxResponse->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'function1'));
    $ajaxResponse->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'function2'));

    return $ajaxResponse;
```

Comment: Does it maybe somehow set isValidated or something like that under the hood? Maybe have a look at how Webform does it in their multistep forms.

Comment: It looks like you're creating a switch to handle each step individually, have you tried creating separate validate callbacks for each step?

Comment: In $form there are multiple '#validated' => true placed everywhere. But changing it doesn't make any difference. In callback methods form_state->setErrorByName creates exception, which means that i can't set error inside callback, only if i return markup with error directly. I don't think it's a good way of doing that, validateForm() is default method for validation and i didn't find any way to replace it for every callback individually and set error inside it.

Comment: I would try adding your individual validation callbacks in buildForm when you're on the appropriate step. If you're on the personal step, add the personal callback to form validation. There's nothing wrong with adding additional validate callbacks.

Comment: @sonfd, you mean validate directly in callback method or something else? Because directly in callback i get exception : "LogicException : Form errors cannot be set after form validation has finished. "

Comment: You know you can have a #validate and #ajax at the same time? @sonfd is referring to #validate. In #ajax callbacks you can't run code on $form or $form_state.

Comment: @4k4, where should i place #validate? Directly in form object or ajax button?

Comment: I tried to place it in form. Inside first callback i change form['#validate] to custom validation method, it didn't work. Tried to add to callback buttons, didn't work as well. Am i making a mistake somewhere?